# Do any contemporary philosophers say "physical" space is ideal, just not the rest of it? Is it possible to?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-physics, space

Do any contemporary philosophers say "physical" space is ideal, just not the rest of it?

Is it possible (I guess, consistent) to say that, even? I do not know what space is in physics.

Comment: What does "ideal" mean? Relational, [as in Leibniz](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-theories/#6.1)? What is "the rest of it"? Relationalism is not very popular today because general relativity can not be formulated in purely relational terms. But neither is substantivalism, the opposite position that space is a real "thing", due to the [hole argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_argument) among other issues. The most popular view is structuralism: space reflects a real structure, but its geometric realization is more or less dispensable.

Comment: i just mean unreal, the "rest of it" being things in space. thanks for helping with the terminology, i should try to improve my question @Conifold